# Visualization of Louvain partitions in Networkx

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx

Please help me change visualize the result of Louvain clustering algorithm.
I took the code from the site
https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain
Can I rewrite the code so that each cluster has its own shape (circle, triangle, square ...)?

```
import community as community_louvain
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# load the karate club graph
G = nx.karate_club_graph()

# compute the best partition
partition = community_louvain.best_partition(G)

# draw the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
# color the nodes according to their partition
cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis', max(partition.values()) + 1)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, partition.keys(), node_size=40,
                       cmap=cmap, node_color=list(partition.values()))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately [`nx.draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes) does not accept an iterable of shapes, so you'll have to loop over the nodes and plot them individually. Also, we'll have to index the generated `cmap`, otherwise, the single valued community values will get mapped to the same initial cmap color. For the possible shapes I'm just replicating the string of available shapes mentioned in the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes) and indexing it based on the partition number:

```
# load the karate club graph
G = nx.karate_club_graph()

# compute the best partition
partition = community_louvain.best_partition(G)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis', max(partition.values()) + 1)
shapes = 'so^>v<dph8'

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
# draw the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
# color the nodes according to their partition
cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis', max(partition.values()) + 1)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.5)
for node, color in partition.items():
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, [node], node_size=100,
                           node_color=[cmap.colors[color]],
                           node_shape=shapes[color])
```

[image]