# How can I cluster a graph g created in NetworkX?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, networkx, embedding

I'm trying to apply clustering to a dataset. Before that i have to divide the graph into n number of clusters and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Here's an example that recently came up https://stackoverflow.com/a/62891137/9698684

Answer (score 7):

Suppose **the edge list** of your **unweighted** and **un-directed** **graph** was saved in file edges.txt. You can follow the steps below to cluster the nodes of the graph.

**Step 1:** get **the embedding of each node** in the graph. That means you need to get a **continuous vector representation** for each node. You can use graph embedding methods like **node2vec**, **deepwalk**, etc to obtain the embedding. Note that such methods preserve the structural similarity between the nodes of a graph in the vector representation (embedding space).  The following example shows how you can do that.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph();
G=nx.read_edgelist("edges.txt") # edges.txt contains the edge list of your graph

# help to draw https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/examples/drawing/labels_and_colors.html
nx.draw(G,with_labels = True,node_color='b',node_size=500);

from node2vec import Node2Vec
# Generate walks
node2vec = Node2Vec(G, dimensions=2, walk_length=20, num_walks=10,workers=4)
# Learn embeddings 
model = node2vec.fit(window=10, min_count=1)
#model.wv.most_similar('1')
model.wv.save_word2vec_format("embedding.emb") #save the embedding in file embedding.emb
```

**Step 2:** apply the clustering method. Once you get vector representation of the nodes, you can cluster the nodes based on those representations. See the example below.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np


X = np.loadtxt("embedding.emb", skiprows=1) # load the embedding of the nodes of the graph
#print(X)
# sort the embedding based on node index in the first column in X
X=X[X[:,0].argsort()]; 
#print(X)
Z=X[0:X.shape[0],1:X.shape[1]]; # remove the node index from X and save in Z

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(Z) # apply kmeans on Z
labels=kmeans.labels_  # get the cluster labels of the nodes.
print(labels)
```

Comment: Any suggestion for weighted and directed graphs?

Comment: For a directed graphsplease use the following code to load the graph and convert it to a directed graph: G=nx.read_weighted_edgelist("edges.txt") and G = G.to_directed(). The other parts should be the same. Node that the edges.txt file contains edges and their weights as well like: SourceNode_ID DestinationNode_ID Weight  ; You can find useful info in https://github.com/agoodweathercc/EmbeddingEval as well.